# is there example that inequality $\sup\{\inf\{f(x,y) : x \in X\}: y \in Y\} \le \inf\{\sup\{f(x,y) : y \in Y\}: x \in X\}$ be strict?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I know it's similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265809/sup-gyy-in-y-leq-inf-fxx-in-x)
and I proved this inequality, but I'm stuck at finding examples that this inequality is strict.
thanks.

Edit: range is bounded.

Comment: with this example both sides will be equal

Comment: Try an example where $X$ and $Y$ each have two elements.

Comment: Thanks Professor but I have tried this as well, but it's equal on every example that crossed my mind

Comment: *Hint:* Find a function such that $\inf\{f(x,y) : x \in X\} = 0$ for all $y$, and $\sup\{f(x,y) : y \in Y\} = 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch no problem, thanks for commenting anyway

Comment: @MartinR, thanks for hint, I thought about this, but problem is finding that example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality can be strict if both $X$ and $Y$ have at least two elements. For an example pick arbitrary elements $x_1 \in X$ and $y_1 \in Y$ and define
$$
 f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
 0 & \text{ if } x=x_1 \text{ and } y = y_1 \\
 1 & \text{ if } x=x_1 \text{ and } y \ne y_1 \\
 1 & \text{ if } x\ne x_1 \text{ and } y = y_1 \\
 0 & \text{ if } x\ne x_1 \text{ and } y \ne y_1 \, .
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\inf\{f(x,y) : x \in X\} = 0$ for all $y \in Y$, and $\sup\{f(x,y) : y \in Y\} = 1$ for all $x \in X$, and therefore
$$
\sup\{\inf\{f(x,y) : x \in X\}: y \in Y\} = 0 < 1 = \inf\{\sup\{f(x,y) : y \in Y\}: x \in X\} \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks, I'm curious that whether we can generalize some patterns about functions shape that this inequality is strict? I thought about it but I couldn't formalize those thoughts

Comment: @mdmi: For some $a < b$ you have to assign function values $\le a$ and $\ge b$ in every “row” and every “column.” –  In the case of real intervals, a simple closed-form example is $f(x, y) = |x-y|$.

Answer (score 1):

Any nonzero linear function should demonstrate this. For example:

Set $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x,y)=x+y$. Then, for any fixed $y^*\in Y$, we have $\inf_{x\in X}f(x,y)=\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}}(x+y^*)\to-\infty$, so $$\sup_{y\in Y}\big(\inf_{x\in X}f(x,y))\big)=\sup_{y\in Y}\{-\infty\}=-\infty.$$
Similarly, for any fixed $x^*\in X$, one can observe $\sup_{y\in Y}f(x,y)\to +\infty$ and hence $$\inf_{x\in X}\big(\sup_{y\in Y}f(x,y)\big)=+\infty,$$
which demonstrates strictness of the linequality.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but can you give an example when range of function is bounded?

Comment: would have been helpful if it were originally stated in the question. Look to Martin R's hint.